# Does each process has its own process table or there is just one process table that maintained by kernel only?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am studying unix operating system. And I am having lot confusion regarding process data structure in unix.

1> Are there separate process tables per processes or only one that only kernel      manipulate based currently active process.

2> Does file descriptor of process resides in its u-area?

Comment: "process tables per processes" - What? Do you mean "file descriptor tables per processes?

Comment: Or, on Windows, "handle tables per processes".

Comment: I was puzzled by this too. What is a "process table?" I've never heard that term before but it may be in used in some operating system. What's "u-area?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *only one process table*, and each process have an entry in that table and it's called a *PCB*, the **pcb** contains most of the information related to the process , **ID**, **owner**, **priority**, the **ppid**, and it also contains information that were stocked in registers if the process is switched into blocked mode, and that's extremely important because all these information are going to be recharged when the process resumes executing.